# How to evaluate if a cron expression is "in the window" at execution?

Tags: java

I have a servlet that reads sale offers from a database and one column is a cron expression, eg `"* 17-23 * * SAT,SUN"`.

This is meant to instruct my application if I should display the sale offer to a customer or not, depending on the current time. So my application needs to have some code to read the offers when someone "hits" the servlet, and then I need to determine at execution time if that each offer must be displayed or not.

So in a nut shell, my java application has to answer the questions "is the time now 'in the window' for a given cron expression"

Quick background: I have never used any library thus far to handle cron expressions, so this is completely new to me.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "So my application needs to have some code" - that's the task of a developer. If you are one, write the code. If you are not a developer, hire one. This site does not provide free coding services

Comment: Oh, and BTW: why use Cron expressions if you are not able to read them? Maybe there's a better format that you can read. You don't need to make your tasks harder than they need to be.

Comment: ahhh ok ... i see the error of my ways! thing is, i dont even know which library to use :facepalm: ... quartz? is that even right? and i sincerely apologise for my error... if i knew how to ask the question better, i truly would have done so

Comment: sadly, the data owner wants to use cron expressions